# Call my VSCode Extension method when another extension command executes

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I have a requirement where my extension method should execute when a Command from another Extension is used by the User.
I just want some guidance on how to do it if it is possible.

Comment: AFAIK there is no event that signals the execution of any command, an extension has no knowledge of the execution of any command other than it's own exported commands

Comment: can you use the extension `multi command` and combine both commands and set a keybinding for that new command

Comment: What does the other extension's command do?

Comment: The Other command sets a Default Username for Salesforce Org.